# Reconhecimento do toque no ecrã, como MouseDown

Tags: c#, winforms, touch

Estou a desenvolver um jogo (Puzzle) em C# WinForms, para correr num ecrã de toque. 
O mapeamento dos eventos de toque para os eventos do rato já ocorrem por defeito, e não tive que fazer nada para que isso acontecesse. No entanto,  o `mouse_down`, apenas ocorre quando eu movo um pouco o meu dedo, e não ocorre no *preciso momento* em que toco o ecrã.

Porque razão isto acontece?
Devo implementar algum tipo de reconhecimento de eventos de toque?

Comment: Quanto tocas no ecrã, o cursor do rato aparece imediatamente no ponto onde tocaste? Ou ele apenas aparece quando moves o dedo? Se ocorre o segundo caso, creio que o problema esteja na forma como esse ecrã específico funciona. Caso contrário, espero que consigas uma boa resposta para tua pergunta.

Comment: Eu neste momento estou a testar num Sony Vaio Tap 20, e quando uso o toque em alternativa ao rato, o habitual cursor desaparece sendo substituído por um circulo. No entanto, este circulo aparece no momento em que ocorre o toque, não sendo necessário efetuar qualquer tipo de movimento.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surgiram outros problemas entretanto, como a sobreposição e dificuldade de distinção entre eventos do toque ou do rato, mas o problema em cima resolvi com o seguinte:

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        switch (m.Msg)
        {
            case Win32.WM_POINTERDOWN:
            case Win32.WM_POINTERUP:
            case Win32.WM_POINTERUPDATE:
            case Win32.WM_POINTERCAPTURECHANGED:
                break;

            default:
                base.WndProc(ref m);
                return;
        }
        int pointerID = Win32.GET_POINTER_ID(m.WParam);
        Win32.POINTER_INFO pi = new Win32.POINTER_INFO();
        if (!Win32.GetPointerInfo(pointerID, ref pi))
        {
            Win32.CheckLastError();
        }
        Point pt = PointToClient(pi.PtPixelLocation.ToPoint());
        MouseEventArgs me = new MouseEventArgs(System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left, 1, pt.X, pt.Y, 0);
        switch (m.Msg)
        {
            case Win32.WM_POINTERDOWN:
                    Console.WriteLine("TOCOU" + pt);
                    (Parent as Jogo).Form1_MouseDown((this as object), me);
                break;

            case Win32.WM_POINTERUP:
                    Console.WriteLine("LEVANTOU");
                    (Parent as Jogo).Form1_MouseUp((this as object), me);
                break;

            case Win32.WM_POINTERUPDATE:
                    //Console.WriteLine("UPDATE");
                    (Parent as Jogo).Form1_MouseMove((this as object), me);
                break;
        }
    }
```

Recorri ao uso de uma classe "Win32.cs" que pode ser descarregada aqui:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4311953/Win32.cs

Espero que seja útil ;)